# Export MySQL column aliases in phpMyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, export

I am currently moving from one ticketing system to another. The table columns are close but not quite. I can run a query that will change the column name to what I need. However, when I export I am getting the original column name.

Here is the query with alias: 
SELECT u.id AS staff_id
FROM users AS u

This gives me what I need. However when I export it, it is showing the original column names. Is there a way to keep the alias when exporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using phpMyAdmin, you can quickly use the "Rename exported databases/tables/columns" feature to rename your table and/or columns when exporting. (I believe this feature was added with version 4.6.0).

On the export page, select the "Custom - display all possible options" radio button, then in the "Output" area look for the "Rename exported databases/tables/columns" checkbox, which opens an additional dialog where you can adjust these names.